# Filter text file on row in python

Tags: python, csv, row

I am trying to filter a text file based on this row in python:

```
'2/2(100%)' 
'2/2(100%)' 
'2/3(67%)'  
'1/2(50%)'  
'3/3(100%)' 
'2/3(67%)'  
'3/3(100%)'
'2/3(67%)'  
'7/9(78%)'  
'17/18(94%
```

I only keep rows where the number after `/` is greater than or equal to 5.
I have managed to get the row information into a list, which I then split on `('/')` and kept the first element. I split that value again on `('(')` and kept the zero element from that operation which is the number. I converted the number to a int and am using it for my if statement (`if number >= 5, writerow()`). But the code is not working right now. This is my code, I have two different way to convert the number to an int:

```
methyl = []
with open("zr518_13_CpG_meth.bed", 'r') as txtfile,         open("zr518_13_CpG_meth_5X.bed", "w") as newfile:
reader = csv.reader(txtfile, delimiter = '\t')
textwriter = csv.writer(newfile, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in reader:
        methyl.append(row[3])
        fragments = [elem.split('/')[1] for elem in methyl]
        numbers = [elems.split('(')[0] for elems in fragments]
        # new_numbers = []
        # for n in numbers:
            # new_numbers.append(int(n))
        for i in range(0,len(numbers)):
            numbers[i]=int(numbers[i])
            if i > 4:
                textwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: The filtering doesn't work, rows with values less than 5 still get written to the new file, basically the whole file is written again, I don't know if the integer value is being saved.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding every row you read to `methyl`, and then check for each row you read, if there is a row in `methyl` with a denominator larger than 4. So when you read a single row with a denominator larger than 4, every row after that will be written to output as many times as there have been rows with a denominator larger than 4 before that.

You can fix this problem by replacing the loop with this:

```
for row in reader:
    denominator = int(row[3].split('/')[1].split('(')[0])
    if denominator > 4:
        textwriter.writerow(row)
```